# Shapiro test on replicated values

Tags: r, statistical-significance, normal-distribution

I have a distribution of frequencies (1000 data points) expressed as %. The list of data looks like this:

> 3.10%
>      1.80%
>      1.70%
>      1.70%
>      1.60%
>      1.60%
>      1.50%

I would like to check for normality distribution of such data using for example the Shapiro test.  I would like to know if I have to remove replicated or if they will stay there, because I performed the test and with the replicated numbers the output is:

> Shapiro-Wilk normality test
>        W = 0.9422, p-value < 2.2e-16

and after removing replicates the output is:

> Shapiro-Wilk normality test
>        W = 0.8911, p-value = 0.05804

So the output change. Is it correct to maintain replicated values since they correspond to real measurements?

Comment: Why would you remove replicates?

Comment: Not only is it correct to keep replicates, it is indefensible to remove them! In terms of what you did:  with 1000 data points, very small deviations from normality will give you results significant at conventional levels. Whether they are of practical importance is a different matter. You should look at a quantile-quantile plot too (normal probability plot, many other names). See `qqnorm` in R.

Comment: If your example means that 3.1 is the largest value, 1.8 next largest, and so on, then it's possible that 3.1 is a mild outlier.

Comment: Hi guys! I really don't want to remove replicates. Just from a theoretical point of view, since I'm not a statistician, I wanted to know if it was correct to consider the replicated points or no. But anyway thanks a lot!!!!!!

Comment: You were spot on with "they correspond to real measurements".